# Eval result with embedding Boo in C#

Tags: c#, boo

I try to embed Boo language in a C# project. The simple code is as follows:

```
var interpreter = new InteractiveInterpreter();

interpreter.Declare("Message", typeof(string));
interpreter.SetValue("Message", "A");
interpreter.Eval(@"
    print Message
    Message = 'B'
    print Message
");

Console.WriteLine(interpreter.GetValue("Message"));
```

The two 'print' commands does not output anything, and the 'Console.WriteLine' cluase output 'A'. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the indentation of the evaluated code. Remove the indentation and it should work as expected.